# How to find the angle subtended to the origin by the unit hyperbola through the point (1,0)?

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to find the angle subtended by the unit hyperbola through the point (1,0). I think that I should be integrating something, but I'm not sure how to set it up. I've been trying to think of this as it would be related to a unit circle, where we would have $R=1$ and then the following
$$
\int_0^{\theta_{0}} R^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)d\theta=R^2\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=(1)(2\pi)=2\pi
$$
So the angle subtended would just be $2\pi$. I know that $1=\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x,$ but as I'm only interested in the right hyperbola, I'm not sure I can use the same trick. Beyond this, I'm stuck. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read $\;$G.A.Jennings *Modern Geometry with Applications* (1994) pp.178-179.

There you find a definition of *hyperbolic angle* (p.178) and a formula (p.179).